# PSexec and windows 2008 server (access denied)

Tags: psexec

I have a program which uses psExec for retrieving environment variables on a remote host. I get the error: Could not start PSEXESVC service on xxhost Access denied.

This command works for windows 2003 servers but not 2008 (it works on 2008 if I run CMD as another user):
psexec \xxhost -u xxdomain\xxuser -p xxpasswrd-h cmd  /c echo %%JAVA_HOME^%%

I also tried creating a connection before executing psexec (with NET USE)-as above, this works on 2003 but not 2008:
NET USE \XXhost
psexec \host cmd  /c echo %%JAVA_HOME^%%

The problem is that I can't use RUNAS in batchfiles as it prompts for password. So, does anybody know how a workaround without having to make changes on the remote server?

Comment: This answer for Windows 7 worked for me, and might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791468/psexec-win7-to-win7-access-denied-psexesvc-remains

Answer (score 19):

It took me hours to find a working way to PsExec between 2 Windows 7 Computers with non-Admin user starting PsExec ... Disabling UAC (EnableLUA=0, ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin=0, LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy=1) did not work, turning off the Firewalls did not work...

Here i found the working way - thanks JelmerS:
(Info from https://serverfault.com/questions/489822/psexec-is-not-connecting-to-machine-using-supplied-username-and-password/489845)

This is because psexec still tries to access the ADMIN$ share with your local credentials, before executing your command as another user. According to this thread, you can cache credentials before executing psexec:

```
cmdkey.exe /add:MACHINE_NAME_HERE /user:MACHINE_NAME_HERE\Administrator /pass:PASSWORD_HERE 
psexec.exe \\MACHINE_NAME_HERE -i notepad
cmdkey.exe /delete:MACHINE_NAME_HERE
```

Comment: Hi wow, had no idea I got a reply on this one. But thanks, looking forward to trying it out!

Comment: It work! Thank you, but I wonder why

psexec.exe \\MACHINE_NAME_HERE -u xxdomain\xxuser -p xxpassword -i notepad

doesn't work, is it a known bug?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PsExec v2.2 and the problem was solved when I used psexec64.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1977162-psexec-32-bit-on-64-bit-host-no-longer-working

Answer (score 0):

For me, even using PSEXEC64 didn't work. Still received the same error. Here's what did work - I had to add the user that was running the psexec command to the remote machine's administrators group and then sign out, then sign in as that user.

But then I was getting a new error: **"Logon Failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer"**

The fix for this problem was to add the -i switch to the command line. This only applies to PSEXEC version 2.30 and higher. So my command prompt looked like this:

```
psexec64 -u domain\username -p password -i \\remotemachinename cmd
```